# Design for archiving a sorted list (with ability for a few INSERT)

Tags: mysql, database-design, archive

I have a somewhat static sorted list of words which I want to save in a database table:

```
-- simplified!
-- Note: the rank/order of each item is NOT calculable from other values!
CREATE table words (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  word NVARCHAR(50),
  -- foreign key
  book_id INTEGER UNSIGNED
);
```

The order of words in a 'book' have to be retained.

**But what is the best way to store the order of all datasets?**

I've already read [How to design a database for storing a sorted list?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5683/how-to-design-a-database-for-storing-a-sorted-list) on this site. But I don't have many `INSERT`s (if I will ever have one) between two records and I don't expect my database to grow up to more than 100k.

So I thought I could use the primary key column `id` for storing the index in the list. But what if I have to insert one record between two `id`s?

The other possibilty is to add another column. Is it better to store the numerical position of the dataset or the neighbour IDs in there?

I'm using MySQL.

---

**Example:**

I have this list from an external resource:

1. house
2. dog
3. browser
4. database

Now I have to enter these values *in same order* into the database!

```
INSERT INTO words (word) VALUES ('house'), ('dog'), ('browser'), ('database')
```

The order is now described via the `id` column (which is the primary key at the same time).

But *suddenly*, I have to insert another word between 'house' and 'dog'.
I can't simply change the PK `id` because that would break other table relations.

Comment: can you use a rank function in a view to return the "id" (rank), this will be computationally intensive, but 100k records is not that many..

Comment: @Rohan But I can't really compute the 'rank' itself. It depends on which word the user saves at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my table `CREATE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE words (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  word NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  rank INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  book_id UNSIGNED INT
);
```

How does it work now?

1. `rank` specifies the **relative** rank (position) within the list of all words of one book (i.e. same `book_id` value)
2. In order to be able to simply insert one word, the application layer (PHP script, etc.) or a trigger on the database side will provide gaps within two ranks instead of incrementing the old one.
   That avoids having to change all entries after the insertion rank (position).

   Because the `rank` is relative to the book, we have a maximum space for 4,294,967,295 ranks. So the rank gap can be choosen very generous.

Thanks to [Richard Vivian](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/16497/richard-vivian) who pointed me to a rank-based solution, and [Joel Brown](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3106/joel-brown) who mentioned the possibility of gaps between two (rank) values.

Answer (score 3):

By all means use an unsigned int surrogate key as your primary, clustered index.  However, instead of using sequential values, build some padding into the sequence.  This means that you'll have to assign the id manually instead of using `auto_increment`.

If you use unsigned int in MySQL, the max value is 4,294,967,295.  If you expect to have at most 100,000 rows that means you could space each word out by more than 42,000.

When you need to insert a word between two existing words, just plug it into the space half way between.  Let's say you use 40,000 as your intitial padding value.  If you have "house" at 800,000 and "dog" at 840,000 you can insert "nouveau" at 820,000.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I had the same idea, but there's still one problem resulting from the oversimplification I made: there is another column called for example **'book_id' which is a PK of another table**. The problem is now that I have to retain the order inside all words belonging to a single 'book'. I could adopt the same approach with gaps but wouldn't it be easier to just add another column?

Comment: @ComFreek - You should keep your foreign key to the other table (`book_id`) in any case.  If your sorting ID needs to be sorted within each book as opposed to overall, then you can still use the gaps approach.  Just sort the words according to whatever combination of factors you need before assigning the sorting IDs with the gaps in them.

Comment: So I just use 0-10,000 for book 1, 10,000-20,000 for book 2?

Comment: @ComFreek - Sure, that should work fine.  It doesn't have to be 10,000 per book.  Just sort all of the words for your initial load by book and then by word order and start loading.  Each word will be 10,000 (or whatever) above the previous word and each book will start and end where ever it happens to.  It doesn't really matter since the word IDs are meaningless except insofar as they are in a particular order.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an auto-number col as the primary key.

Add another col for the rank.

When adding a new item to the table set If the rank is last set the rank to be MAX(RANK) +1.

If the rank is in the middle increment the rank of all other items , by the following.

```
UPDATE Words SET  Rank = Rank +1 where Rank >= CurrentRankReplacedId
```

I agree, this is something that you can not calculate , and will need to store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think you have misunderstood me. I've included an example in the question body which should make things clearer. I also forgot to say that I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Apologies ComFreek, hope this is a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Hi Richard, I've just found another solution combining a rank mechanism and gaps (as Joel said). I'll post a solutino tomorrow ;) +1 for you both BTW.